# How to get Customer Group collection in frontend customer form in magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3

i have created custom customer registration form , how  to display customer group in dropdown menu please help me..

Comment: Dropdown menu where?

Comment: I want to add dropdown menu in My custom form frontendside @Dominic Xigen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please create module and add below code in Block file.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\CustomerGroup\Block;

class CustomerGroup extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\CollectionFactory $groupCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->groupCollectionFactory = $groupCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve customer group collection
     *
     * @return GroupCollection
     */
    public function getCustomerGroupCollection()
    {
        if (!$this->hasData('customer_group_collection')) {
            $collection = $this->groupCollectionFactory->create();
            $this->setData('customer_group_collection', $collection);
        }

        return $this->getData('customer_group_collection');
    }
```

And then you can get customer group data in template file

```
<?php
$customerGroupCollection = $block->getCustomerGroupCollection();
foreach($customerGroupCollection as $customerGroup) {
    echo 'ID '.$customerGroup->getId();
    echo 'Code '.$customerGroup->getCode();
    echo 'Tax class Id '.$customerGroup->getTaxClassId();
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Hope it will work for you

Comment: Yes it is helpful there is any way to display only wholesaler, distributor, retailor group onlydisplay?

Comment: You can add a condition by $customerGroup->getCode()

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code :

```
<?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$groupOptions = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection')->toOptionArray();
  ?>
<select>
     <?php foreach($groupOptions as $groupOption) { ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $groupOption->getId(); ?>"><?php echo $groupOption->getCode(); ?></optinon>
     <?php } ?>
</select>
```